# How to use $match with conditional if-else?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i wanted to make conditional query where `if councilPeriod not equal to 1 i can use condition where person with same families_id in other person families array showing up else that condition disabled`.

```
const families = await People.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$families'
        }
      },
      { $project: { Ids: '$families._id' } }
    ]);

    const families_id = families.map(function(i) {
      return i.Ids;
    });

    const people = await People.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          nia: 1,
          name: 1,
          address: 1,
          sector: 1,
          status: 1,
          grazing: 1,
          councilPeriod: 1,
          crtdDiff: { $subtract: [new Date(), '$dateJoined'] },
          sidiDiff: { $subtract: [new Date(), '$dateSidi'] }
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          status: 'Active',
          _id: { $nin: families_id },
          grazing: 'Tidak',
          councilPeriod: { $ne: 1 },
          crtdDiff: { $gt: 63072000000 },
          sidiDiff: { $gt: 63072000000 }
        }
      }
    ]);
```

i expect a query if person with councilPeriod not equal 1 then the families also showing up, else the opposite. Thank youu.

Comment: To understand your question properly can you post the sample document and desired output? you can use https://mongoplayground.net/ and post your sample document then click share link to share the link. Then anyone can edit the query for you. We need sample document and desired output for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if condition in aggregation like ,

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project:
           {
             item: 1,
             discount:
               {
                 $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$councilPeriod", 1 ] }, then: _anyCondition_, 
                else: _anyCondition_ }
               }
           }
      }
   ]
)
```

Hope you find it useful .